# Puppet v7.27.0 module to write and execute file not executing

Tags: puppet

I'm new to puppet, and I'm attempting to make a module which will:

1. copy a binary file from the server to the agents
2. execute the file

I have attempted to follow [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.10/html/puppet_guide/chap-red_hat_satellite-puppet_guide-building_puppet_modules_from_scratch#sect-Red_Hat_Satellite-Puppet_Guide-Building_Puppet_Modules_from_Scratch-Examining_the_Anatomy_of_a_Puppet_Module) and several 'hello world' examples, however none of them seem to work on version 7+ or are several years out of date.

Puppet version is 7.27.0, using a docker compose from https://github.com/voxpupuli/crafty

I'm currently using `dsvuhtqkng` as my module name, which is just a temporary place holder.

My folder/file structure is as follows:

```
root@puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules# ls -lahR
.:
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Dec 15 10:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 dsvuhtqkng

./dsvuhtqkng:
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 files
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 manifests

./dsvuhtqkng/files:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root  250 Dec 17 21:51 wget

./dsvuhtqkng/manifests:
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 17 21:51 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   53 Dec 17 21:51 init.pp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  243 Dec 17 21:51 binary.pp
```

my `init.pp` is:

```
class dsvuhtqkng () {
  contain dsvuhtqkng::binary
}
```

I've also tried it w/o the `()` and using `include` instead of `contain`.

my `binary.pp` is:

```
class binary {
      file { '/tmp/wget':
    ensure => file,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/dsvuhtqkng/wget',
    owner  => root,
    group  => root,
    mode   => '775',
  }
  exec { '/tmp/wget' }
}
```

The output from `puppet module list` does see the module:

```
root@puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules# puppet module list
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
└── dsvuhtqkng (???)
/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules (no modules installed)
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

Running `puppet agent -t` doesn't execute the module:

```
root@puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules# puppet agent -t
Info: Using environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for puppet
Info: Applying configuration version '1702848637'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
```

So I believe I have a disconnect between `init.pp` which seems to be read and understood by `puppet module list` and the actual execution of `binary.pp`.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

In theory, if I could include everything in `init.pp` instead of also needing `binary.pp` that would be great as well.

Comment: The `dsvuhtqkng` class is not in the catalog. The reason for that depends on how you are classifying and compiling catalogs for your nodes which is unknown information. The next issue would be a compilation error because your `binary` manifest defines a class named `payload` instead of the enforced namespace `dsvuhtqkng::binary` class name. After that the next issue would be that the `exec` resource requires a dependency on the `file` resource. There may continue to be more issues after that.

Comment: you are right on the `payload` vs `binary`, that was a sanitization error on my end.

None of the tutorials I've read have mentioned a catalog, I saw some old ones mention `site.pp`, which i assume is the old version of this?
Per [spec](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-command), it looks like `command` isn't needed as it defaults to the title.
Can you explain the exec/file portion? I looked through the docs for exec and there's only one thing that seems relevant, but I believe the file call before it should handle getting the file there.

Comment: @swampPI, the Puppet docs discuss [catalogs, where they come from, and how they are used](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/subsystem_catalog_compilation.html).  In short, the Puppet server responds to agent requests by using the node's facts, the manifests and data you provide on the server, and any external classification you specify to build a catalog, which is what it conveys to the agent to describe the desired state of the target node.

Comment: You are more than likely serving **empty** catalogs, on account of not providing for any node classification, which is where you tell Puppet which classes and resources to apply to the target node.  Just because you've defined a class does not mean that it should be applied to every node.  Or to any particular node.